# AWS CDK and AppSync: Invalid principal in policy: "SERVICE":"appsync"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync

I'm trying to follow tutorials and use AWS's CDK CLI to deploy a stack using AppSync and some resource creations fail with errors like the following showing under events for the Stack in the CloudFormation console:

> Invalid principal in policy: "SERVICE":"appsync" (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedPolicyDocument; Request ID: 8d98f07c-d717-4dfe-af96-14f2d72d993f; Proxy: null)

I suspect what happened is that when cleaning up things on my personal developer account I deleted something I shouldn't have, but due to limited AWS experience I don't know what to create, I suspect it's an IAM policy, but I don't know the exact settings to use.

I'm trying on a new clean project created using `cdk init sample-app --language=typescript`. Running `cdk deploy` immediately after the above command works fine.

I originally tried using [cdk-appsync-transformer](https://github.com/kcwinner/cdk-appsync-transformer) to create GraphQL endpoints to a DynamoDB table and encountered the error.

I tried re-running `cdk bootstrap` after deleting the `CDKToolkit` CloudFormation stack, but it's not fixing this problem.

To rule out that it's due to something with the 3rd party library, I tried using AWS's own [AppSync Construct Library](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_appsync-readme.html#dynamodb) instead and even following the example there I encountered the same error (although on creation of different resource types).

### Reproduction steps

- Create a new folder.
- In the new folder run `cdk init sample-app --language=typescript`.
- Install the AWS AppSync Construct Library: `npm i @aws-cdk/aws-appsync-alpha@2.58.1-alpha.0 --save`.
- As per [AWS's docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-appsync-alpha-readme.html#dynamodb):

  - Create `lib/schema.graphql` with the following:

    ```
    type demo {
        id: String!
        version: String!
    }
    type Query {
        getDemos: [ demo! ]
    }
    input DemoInput {
        version: String!
    }
    type Mutation {
        addDemo(input: DemoInput!): demo
    }
    ```
  - Update the `lib/<projectName>-stack.ts` file to be essentially like the following:

    ```js
    import * as appsync from '@aws-cdk/aws-appsync-alpha';
    import { Duration, Stack, StackProps } from 'aws-cdk-lib';
    import * as dynamodb from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-dynamodb';
    import * as sns from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-sns';
    import * as subs from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-sns-subscriptions';
    import * as sqs from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-sqs';
    import { Construct } from 'constructs';
    import * as path from 'path';

    export class CdkTest3Stack extends Stack {
        constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: StackProps) {
            super(scope, id, props);

            const queue = new sqs.Queue(this, 'CdkTest3Queue', {
                visibilityTimeout: Duration.seconds(300)
            });

            const topic = new sns.Topic(this, 'CdkTest3Topic');

            topic.addSubscription(new subs.SqsSubscription(queue));

            const api = new appsync.GraphqlApi(this, 'Api', {
                name: 'demo',
                schema: appsync.SchemaFile.fromAsset(path.join(__dirname, 'schema.graphql')),
                authorizationConfig: {
                    defaultAuthorization: {
                        authorizationType: appsync.AuthorizationType.IAM,
                    },
                },
                xrayEnabled: true,
            });

            const demoTable = new dynamodb.Table(this, 'DemoTable', {
                partitionKey: {
                    name: 'id',
                    type: dynamodb.AttributeType.STRING,
                },
            });

            const demoDS = api.addDynamoDbDataSource('demoDataSource', demoTable);

            // Resolver for the Query "getDemos" that scans the DynamoDb table and returns the entire list.
            // Resolver Mapping Template Reference:
            // https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-mapping-template-reference-dynamodb.    html
            demoDS.createResolver('QueryGetDemosResolver', {
                typeName: 'Query',
                fieldName: 'getDemos',
                requestMappingTemplate: appsync.MappingTemplate.dynamoDbScanTable(),
                responseMappingTemplate: appsync.MappingTemplate.dynamoDbResultList(),
            });

            // Resolver for the Mutation "addDemo" that puts the item into the DynamoDb table.
            demoDS.createResolver('MutationAddDemoResolver', {
                typeName: 'Mutation',
                fieldName: 'addDemo',
                requestMappingTemplate: appsync.MappingTemplate.dynamoDbPutItem(
                    appsync.PrimaryKey.partition('id').auto(),
                    appsync.Values.projecting('input'),
                ),
                responseMappingTemplate: appsync.MappingTemplate.dynamoDbResultItem(),
            });

            //To enable DynamoDB read consistency with the `MappingTemplate`:
            demoDS.createResolver('QueryGetDemosConsistentResolver', {
                typeName: 'Query',
                fieldName: 'getDemosConsistent',
                requestMappingTemplate: appsync.MappingTemplate.dynamoDbScanTable(true),
                responseMappingTemplate: appsync.MappingTemplate.dynamoDbResultList(),
            });
        }
    }
    ```
- Run `cdk deploy`.

Comment: Hard to say without the code.  Are you writing AppSync-related IAM policy constructs yourself?  A valid AppSync Service Principal in an IAM policy statement looks like `"Principal": { "Service": "appsync.amazonaws.com" }` in the [synthed template](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cli.html#cli-synth) in `cdk.out`.

Comment: I've updated the question with reproduction steps. I'm not writing explicit policy constructs myself, only the constructs which I guess use them / expect them to be present.

Comment: Right, no smoking guns in the code.  Does a stripped-down stack without AppSync resources deploy?  Perhaps an AppSync resource is just the first to fail.

Comment: Yes, `cdk init sample-app --language=typescript` followed immediately by `cdk deploy` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

[AppSync L2 Construct](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_appsync-readme.html) is now stable. You can use this version instead of alpha release. When I switched it, the error was gone.

```
- import * as appsync from '@aws-cdk/aws-appsync-alpha';
+ import * as appsync from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-appsync';
```